# Using awk and grep command in for loop

Tags: shell, awk, grep, ksh

Consider below code snippet:

```
#! /bin/ksh
for i in `grep "ProcessOrderWebService-N" Orders.Log | grep "::stringFromNetwork  =  600001" | awk -F',' '{print $1}'`; do
    echo $i;
done;

2015-05-26
10:20:10
2015-05-26
10:20:49
2015-05-26
10:21:45
```

From the command prompt, when I run the command:

```
grep "ProcessOrderWebService-N" Orders.Log | grep "::stringFromNetwork  =  600001" | awk -F',' '{print $1}'
```

The output received is as below.

```
2015-05-26 10:20:10
2015-05-26 10:20:49
2015-05-26 10:21:45
```

The `grep` pattern that I am searching in the file `Orders.Log` is as below:

```
2015-05-26 10:20:10,847 : ProcessOrderWebService-N|220082|1|::stringFromNetwork  =  600001 - reference number is 26000033
```

Basically I want to get the output in for loop as `2015-05-26 10:20:10`. Where as in the above case, the date and time are printed in different lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple `grep`s and `awk`s in pipes are never needed. Mostly the job can be done with one single tool:

```
grep -oP '^[^,]+(?=.*ProcessOrderWebService-N.*::stringFromNetwork  =  600001)' file
```

Gives the desired list. If your really need a `for` loop, your have to change the [internal field separator](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html) first:

```
IFS=$'\n'
for line in $(grep -oP '^[^,]+(?=.*ProcessOrderWebService-N.*::stringFromNetwork  =  600001)' file); do
  echo $line
done
```

But, I recommend a `while` loop, when you deal with lines:

```
grep -oP '^[^,]+(?=.*ProcessOrderWebService-N.*::stringFromNetwork  =  600001)' file | while read line; do
  echo $line
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using ksh shell. Is there any alternative to grep option -oP in ksh ?

Comment: @user2531564 This works in ksh as well, I tested it. What is your grep version: `grep --version`

Comment: I am using solaris UNIX 5.10 Generic_147147-26 sun4u sparc SUNW,SPARC-Enterprise

Comment: @user2531564 I don't have a solaris box to test, sry. But, then use the part in your question. Just set the `IFS` variable as mentioned in my question. Or the `while` solution: `grep ... | grep .. | awk ... | while read line; do ... done`, works too

Comment: Hey.. It working.. I will use while for looping.. Thanks a lot. Could u please let me know the advantage of while over for loop.

Comment: @user2531564 for uses the IFS to determine the separator of the list, `while` with `read` instead is simpler to loop line by line. To be precisely, after the for loop you have to set the IFS variable back to its original value.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're using a `for` loop, which iterates over ($IFS separated) **words** not **lines**. Use a `while read` loop to iterate over lines:

```
#!/bin/ksh
grep "ProcessOrderWebService-N" Orders.Log |
grep "::stringFromNetwork  =  600001" |
awk -F',' '{print $1}' |
while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "$line"
done
```

However, as chaos suggests, all the work can be done in a single tool. On your solaris box, awk would be the better tool:

```
awk -F, '/ProcessOrderWebService-N/ && /::stringFromNetwork  =  600001/ {print $1}' Orders.Log
```